# Ajax escape_javascript method does not delete previous rendered partial in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, haml, railstutorial.org

I'm new in Ruby on Rails so I decided to do railstutorial.org's tutorial. I stuck on chapter 12, listing 12.37-38. I converted all html.erb files into html.haml (in chapter 7). I want Ajax to replace partials after clicking Follow/Unfollow button but right now when I click e.g. Follow button, Unfollow button is appearing above Follow and this Follow button is not disappearing.

Sth like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk0hM.png.

After that when I'm clicking on upper button it successfully replaces rendering of Follow/Unfollow partials but the button above(in this case Follow) will be visible until page is refreshed. What I am doing wrong?

destroy.js.erb:

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'users/follow' ) %>");
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>');
```

create.js.erb:

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'users/unfollow' ) %>");
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>');
```

show.html.haml:

```
- provide(:title, @user.name)
.row
  %aside.col-md-4
    %section.user_info
      %h1 
        = gravatar_for @user
        = @user.name
    %section.stats
      = render 'shared/stats'
  .col-md-8
    = render 'follow_form' if logged_in?
    - if @user.microposts.any?
      %h3 
        Microposts (#{@user.microposts.count})
      %ol.microposts
        = render @microposts
      = will_paginate @microposts
```

follow_form partial:

```
- unless current_user?(@user)
  %div#follow_form
  - if current_user.following?(@user)
    = render 'unfollow'
  - else
    = render 'follow'
```

unfollow partial:

```
= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id), html: { method: :delete}, remote: true) do |f| 
  = f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn"
```

follow partial:

```
= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build, remote: true) do |f| 
  %div
    = hidden_field_tag :followed_id, @user.id
  = f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

relationships_controller.rb:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end 
  end 

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [chapter where this feature is described](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users) you aren't quite using the right syntax for the render call. It should be:

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>");
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>');
```

Note the extra brackets after the render call that wraps around 'users/unfollow' - the same is true for your other call:

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>");
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: nope, changing that didn't help and the brackets for methods in ruby are optional so render 'users/unfollow' == render('users/unfollow')

Comment: Is the follow_form div closed out with a </div> correctly? Sometimes I've had similar behaviour when I've not quite setup the DOM correctly.

Comment: yup thx a lot ! that was the problem, i put that renders out of a div